# How to check total RAM memory available in a VPS in *realtime* ..?

Tags: java, memory, ubuntu, vps, ram

I recently purchased a VPS, and on paper its supposed to give me 1 GB of dedicated memory and another 1 GB of burstable memory ... So at any given time, the total amount of memory that should be available to me should be between 1 GB and 2 GB, right ? Correct me if I'm wrong ..

How can I check this from within my Ubuntu VPS ? So that I know I'm getting what I'm paying for ..

I want to check this because I installed Java on the VPS, and its not running due to having insufficient memory available ..

By the way, I know of the 'free' command ... Question is, would it serve my purpose ?

**EDIT**: The reason why I think I'm running low on memory is because when I have a VPN session on and I type in `java` in the console, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

However, if I restart the VPS and do not start the VPN service, and instead just login through ssh again and type in `java`, I get the correct response (all java parameters listed, etc) ...

Comment: I withdrew my answer in light of your update. I find it quite unlikely,though, that you are being cheated on your VPS params.

Comment: One other thought, your environment may be different when you login differently.

Answer (score 0):

Java only required 64MB of RAM to run on Linux box http://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml

If it print "out of memory error", then the problem probably in your Java program.

to check memory allocation in Linux, use free command or "cat /proc/meminfo"

Comment: I just added some more information (why I think I'm running out of memory) .. Kindly revise your answer if you think it should be updated in light of the new information ..

Comment: I tried using `cat /proc/meminfo`, but the response I got indicated a *very* large amount of memory (around 8 TB I think!) .. I not really sure what this means .. maybe its the total memory of their server (which may be running other VPSs as well), and not the memory allocated specifically for my own VPS ... The output of this command is available here: http://pastebin.com/Tf17px1Z

Comment: what is the "ulimit" command output ? when you VPN to the VPS

Comment: found this link http://devnulled.com/content/2007/06/how-to-display-linux-vps-memory-usage/ - it works only with Virtuozzo VPS, btw.

Comment: output for `ulimit` is unlimited .. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

These [howto](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-check-realtime-ram-memory-usage-available-in-linux-vps/) will check realtime RAM memory usage available in Linux VPS using watch command.

a. Check memory usage using “top” command. Watch command not required for top command as top will update the result periodically. :

## top

b. Check memory usage using “/proc/meminfo” with watch command :

## watch -n 1 cat /proc/meminfo

c. Check memory usage using “free” with watch command :

## watch -n 1 free

d. Check memory usage using “vmstat” with watch command :

## watch -n 1 vmstat

Answer (score 0):

instead of viewing the static used memory, you can view the live usage using htop. all of the commands suggested show the ram available/used at a point in time. htop allows you to view the dedicated ram and the swap ram usage updated in 1 second intervals which makes it easier to understand your services ram needs. htop also shows the live usage of your cpu's.

Run this command on ubuntu to install htop

```
   sudo apt-get install htop
```

then run htop with

```
   htop
```

good luck